# Comparing birthdays and ages in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL DB with a table (USERS) that stores a lot of user information including the following columns:

> dob_day, dob_month, dob_year

I need to get the age of the user (exact age, not just by using the year).

This query will be used in conjunction with a search box with two drop-downs where the user selects the low_are and high_age and compares it to the age calculated above.

> (users_age >= $low_age AND users_age <= $high_age)

Any help with this would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: the dates should be in one date field not three

Comment: Dagon's suggestion would certainly help, if you're able to alter the table.

Comment: @Dagon It is all a matter of different preferences/implementation.  There is no right or wrong answer on the fields.

Comment: you lose all the built in date functions doing it this way, so where's the advantage? I see only a down side.

Comment: @Dagon I would agree I can see no advantage in separating the fields. The downsides I can identify are: 1) an incorrect date can be stored e.g. 31 Feb 2011 which isn't ideal (Granted validation of input values is usually performed using PHP, but this opens up the opportunity for a bug). 2) the query I have specified will take a lot longer to run than if you just had a date field for dob.

Comment: Thanks guys. The only reason I used the 3 fields to store the DOB is that on the join form for this app we have 3 drop-down boxes, for MM, DD and YYYY, so I just stored them like that. And it is faster to pick users that were born in specific months, but not easier to calculate real ages. Which could still be calculated from PHP if I had that data in one field.

Answer (score 0):

Put the birthday in a dob_date, and the following select should work.

```
SELECT year(curdate()) - year(dob_date) 
       + if((month(curdate() > month(dob_date)) 
             or (month(curdate()) = month(dob_date) 
                 and day(curdate()) >= day(dob_date)),1,0) as age from ...
```

Please don't kill me if I forgot a '(' or ')', but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a string comparison of dates:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS('-', dob_year, dob_month, dob_day), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '1950-01-01' 
AND   DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS('-', dob_year, dob_month, dob_day), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2005-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the structure as you have specified you could use the following code query to select these users:

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(a.dob) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(a.dob,5))) as 'age'  FROM (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(dob_day,',',dob_month,',',dob_year), '%d,%m,%Y') AS 'dob' FROM users) a WHERE  (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(a.dob) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(a.dob,5))) BETWEEN $low_age AND $high_age
```

Please see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html) for details about the calculation used to work out a user's age.

You can easily modify the query above to extract other user fields from the table.